# Problem in ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, comautomationfactory

I tried to create object using ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject . It is giving following exception

```
     "Failed to create an object instance for the specified ProgId"
```

My application is running on OOB and has elevated permission.

if (ComAutomationFactory.IsAvailable && App.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
                {

```
                dynamic sample = ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject("SampleCom.ComClass");

            }
```

where SampleCom is a my Com Application created in C#

I use Silverlight 4

Comment: You'll need to get a better error message to diagnose this.  I recommend you use a debugger.

Comment: Only if the Dll is signed you can Create object using ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the Dll is signed you can Create object using ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject

Comment: This solved my problem, but could you point me towards *any* documentation that says the COM component must be signed? So far I've only seen statements about how the XAP file of the Silverlight application should be signed.